# React.js: How to expand only the content of the clicked property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to expand/collapse the content of the clicked property, but clicking expands all the properties. 
 I understand that I need to expand the item based on some `indentifier`, like if the idx of icon is the same as the idx of the item, then expand only that item, but can't implement in code.

Here is [the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-wozniak-ffjufp?file=/src/ArticleItem.js:0-197) and code example below
App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import ArticleItem from "./ArticleItem";
import { useState } from "react";

const ARTICLES = [
  {
    title: "What's SAP",
    upvotes: 1,
    date: "2019-11-21"
  },
  {
    title: "Simple text editor has 15k monthly users",
    upvotes: 7,
    date: "2010-12-31"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleView = (idx) => {
    return ARTICLES.map((_, index) => {
      if (idx === index) {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {ARTICLES.map((article, idx) => (
        <div>
          {article.title}
          <button onClick={() => toggleView(idx)}>
            <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
          </button>
          {isOpen && <ArticleItem article={article} />}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ArticleItem.js

```
import React from "react";

const ArticleItem = ({ article }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{article.upvotes}</div>
      <div>{article.date}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ArticleItem;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Each `ArticleItem` should contain its own state of whether or not it's expanded. The parent should not have to micromanage its children.

Comment: @caTS thanks for the comment. 
Does it mean that I need to validate in child component?
IF yes, could you show in sandbox, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have *one boolean value*:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
```

This boolean value doesn't *store* the information of *which* article to display, only to either display or not display.

> I understand that I need to expand the item based on some indentifier

Then store an identifier instead of just a boolean.  For example, if you're using the index position as your identifier, store that.  Start with some default:

```
const [openArticle, setOpenArticle] = useState(-1);
```

Since `-1` won't match any index, none of them will be open by default.  Use that value to drive the rendering:

```
{openArticle === idx && <ArticleItem article={article} />}
```

And update that value in your click handler:

```
const toggleView = (idx) => {
  setOpenArticle(idx);
};
```

---

If re-clicking the same index should close it, add that logic as well:

```
const toggleView = (idx) => {
  if (openArticle === idx) {
    setOpenArticle(-1);
  } else {
    setOpenArticle(idx);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Each article should be its own component with its own state:

```js
      {ARTICLES.map((article, i) => (
        <ArticleItem key={i} article={article} />
      ))}
```

Generally if you find that the parent must manage a child's state, you probably have something wrong and you should move the state of the child into the child itself.

So taking that into consideration, I have moved the `isOpen` state to the `ArticleItem` component:

```js
const ArticleItem = ({ article }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {article.title}
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>
        <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </button>
      {isOpen && (
        <>
          <div>{article.upvotes}</div>
          <div>{article.date}</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now the button will expand and only expand the article it is for.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-shamir-2b78ir?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Have each child manage its own state of open or closed.

```
export default function App() {
  const ARTICLES = [
   ...
  ];

  let articles = ARTICLES.map((i) => {
    return (
      <ArticleItem
        key={i.id}
        title={i.title}
        upvotes={i.upvotes}
        date={i.date}
      />
    );
  });

  return <div className="App">{articles}</div>;
}
```

Then in the child:

```
const ArticleItem = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleView = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{props.title}</div>
      {isOpen && (
        <>
          <div>{props.upvotes}</div>
          <div>{props.date}</div>
        </>
      )}
      <button onClick={() => toggleView()}>
        <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default ArticleItem;
```